# Why my LinkedList doesn't contains addLast() method?

Tags: java, oop, collections

I have a strange problem I really can't understand.

I've created a **LinkedList** in this way:

```
List<String> customList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

If check the type of `customList` using `list instanceof LinkedList` i get `true`, so customList is a LinkedList.

Now, if I try to execute the method addLast() on customList i get an Eclipse error:

```
 The method addLast(String) is undefined for the type List<String>
```

The method addList is defined in the class [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) but the only way to use this method is to declare customList as a LinkedList and not as a List, in this way:

```
LinkedList<String> customList= new LinkedList<String>();
```

or I have to use a cast:

```
((LinkedList<String>) list).addLast(...);
```

I really don't understand this kind of behaviour, is there someone who can give me some hint? Can you also give me some link or other reference in order to understand this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`addLast` is declared in the `LinkedList` class, but not in the `List` interface. Therefore you can only call it using variables of `LinkedList` type. However, for a variable of `List` type you can call `add` instead, since it adds the element to the end of the `List`.

When the compiler sees a `List` variable, it doesn't know the runtime type of the object that would be assigned to that variable. Therefore it can only let you call methods of the `List` interface. For example, you might assign to your variable an `ArrayList` instance which doesn't have an `addLast` method, so it can't let you call methods of `LinkedList` that are not declared in `List` (or a super-interface of `List`).

Comment: Ok but my customList is a LinkedList, according to instanceof. So I expect that I can use all method of LinkedList

Comment: @EmanueleGiarlini But you can easily assign an ArrayList instance to the same variable, and ArrayList has no addLast method. That's why the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: Your customList is a LinkedList *now*, but it could be any kind of List later as Eran explained, so the compiler doesn't allow to use non-List methods. A compiler doesn't execute the code (simply examines it to match some rules) and it's not able to predict what customList would be in execution time. 
If you don't need polymorphism here, there is no need to declare it as a List.You should check some references about polymorphism in programming to know more about this.